# How to give form fields unique names in MVC WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I'm trying to get inline (aka in-cell) editing working in an MVC WebGrid, using Ajax requests to post changed data. I'm using data annotations to specify validation rules on my models.

A typical grid column definition looks something like:

```
grid.Column("Name", GridHelper.Sort("Name", "Name", grid), format:
        @<text>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => item.Name)
        </text>)
```

The editor template includes a validation message.

The problem is that all of the 'Name' fields have the same name ID 'item_Name'; I would have hoped MVC was clever enough to add an index suffix or something, but it obviously isn't. So the validation messages are displayed for *all* fields of the same name, even if there is only an issue with one of them.

I suppose the solution is to somehow set unique IDs for all of the fields. I know I could use `input' elements to do this, but I would much prefer to continue to use the HTML helpers with editor templates.

Comment: I was going to suggest input elements but it looks like you've thought of that already. You can add unique ID's however, if you use a for loop you can set the ids using "new { @id = 'your_id_' + i) }" as a parameter to the html helper